# synchronous request google maps geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding

How can we synchronous following request. Because its asynchronous by default.

```
 $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="'+address[x]+' '+zipcode_true[x]+' '+city[x]+' '+state[x]+'"&sensor=false',null,function (data) { 
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
 var latlng_marker = new Array();
 latlng_marker[x] = latlng;  
});
```

Comment: but why? This async nature seems better choice.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent to the following synchronous code:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    data: {
        address: address[x] + ' ' + zipcode_true[x] + ' ' + city[x]  + ' ' + state[x],
        sensor: false
    }
});

var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
var latlng_marker = new Array();
latlng_marker[x] = latlng;
```